# In multivariate analysis using PERMANOVA and NMDS, is it appropriate to include both predictors in my model?

Tags: r, vegan, multivariate-testing

I am an undergrad student new to much of these stats. I am using NMDS ordination and Permanova testing to analyze variation in cover type (using count data) at different distance classes (0, 3, 10 m) from ponds at 21 sites. I have two predictor variables: burn zone (within burn zone or not burned) and elevation (continuous, m). For the NMDS ordination and Permanova tests I have been running these predictors separately using adonis function in vegan (code here):

Distlm or Permanova for elevation at 0m distance class:

```
distlm0<-adonis(samp0 ~ data0$Elevation_m, permutations = 9999, method = "bray",
                strata = NULL)
```

Permanova for burn zone at 0m distance class:

```
adonisburn0<-adonis(samp0 ~ group_burn, permutations = 9999, method = "bray",
                   strata = NULL)
```

Is it appropriate/ possible to run these two predictors together? How would I go about this?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. Note that `adonis` performs sequential tests of the terms (i.e. the order of your terms in the formula matters), but there is also an `adonis2` function which can perform sequential, marginal and overall tests.

If using `adonis2` you can specify which test to perform using the `by` argument. `by = "terms"` will assess significance for each term (sequentially from first to last), setting `by = "margin"` will assess the marginal effects of the terms (each marginal term analysed in a model with all other variables), and `by = NULL` will assess the overall significance of all terms together.

e.g.

```
adonis2(samp0 ~ Elevation + group_burn, by="margin", permutations=9999, method="bray")
```

You could also test for an interaction between multiple predictors e.g. `Elevation * group_burn`.

Note that `strata` is deprecated in adonis2: if necessary, you can define similar structure (blocks) in `permutations`